New issues rebasing my branch via SourceTree
I recently had to reset my Sourcetree (it's used for pushing and pulling to branches) and it caused some issues.
Previously when I was working on my branch and needed to merge master into it it worked just fine. I'd be on my branch, select "Rebase current changes into master" and I'd get master code on my branch.
Now when I do the same it reverts the code change which was made on master and pushes the revert on my branch.
I think there is a simple command to set up the default and I ran the wrong one resetting my Source tree but could not find it.
When I rebased the first time i think it gave me two options i and chose the wrong one.
To be completely clear. Let's say, I'm working on file A and add aaa to it. On my branch A1, while I'm working on it somebody pushes MR with adding bbb to file B on branch B. This change is merged to master before my branch A.
I was my branch A to have changes to file B from branch B. But when I rebase it pushes changes to file B being removed, not added. I do not want to remove anything previously committed to master, just added. I was able to do it before with the same select "Rebase current changes into master" right clicking on master and now I can't.
